# Device not found. NO GPU output 3 Computers same issue?

Tags: mining-hardware

I have 3 computers that I want to use for mining when idle. 2 of them are windows 7 one of the is windows 8 all three are x64 base. two of them have 7700hd ATI cards and the third has a 7870HD XFX. All three are having same issue. No output. No GPU found on the devices. All three computes have same look on the screen no devices found. I have used catalyst drivers from V12.8-V13.11 and same with the SDKs I have used different versions of CGminer (V2.11.4 just crashes on startup). I would like to blow out the CPU's as well but that's another issue all together. My command lines along with my startup screens are below.

Please include your bitcoin/litecoin address with reply.

Thank you for your time!

```
        cgminer -o ltc.give-me-coins.com:3333
```

CGMiner

### cgminer version 3.8.5 - Started: [2013-12-14 16:02:44]

(5s):0.000 (avg):0.000h/s | A:0  R:0  HW:0  WU:0.0/m
 ST: 2  SS: 0  NB: 1  LW: 2  GF: 0  RF: 0
 Connected to ltc.give-me-coins.com diff 16 with stratum as user

### Block: cd82d7df...  Diff:2.93K  Started: [16:02:44]  Best share: 0

### [P]ool management [S]ettings [D]isplay options [Q]uit

[2013-12-14 16:02:38] Started cgminer 3.8.5
 [2013-12-14 16:02:40] No devices detected!

```
        bfgminer.exe -o ltc.give-me-coins.com:3333
```

BFG miner

bfgminer version 3.8.1 - Started: [2013-12-14 16:01:01] - [  0 days 00:01:08]
[M]anage devices [P]ool management [S]ettings [D]isplay options  [H]elp [Q]uit
Connected to ltc.give-me-coins.com diff 16 with stratum as user 
Block: ...9616fd46 #479102  Diff:2.93k (20.95Gh/s)  Started: [16:01:01]
ST:2  F:0  NB:1  AS:0  BW:[631/ 20 B/s]  E:0.00  I: 0.00 BTC/hr  BS:0

### 0            |   0.0/  0.0/  0.0 h/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none

---

[2013-12-14 16:01:00] Waiting for devices; press 'M+' to add, or 'Q' to quit
[2013-12-14 16:01:00] Probing for an alive pool
[2013-12-14 16:01:01] Pool 0 http://ltc.give-me-coins.com:3333 alive

Answer (score 1):

Cgminer stopped supporting GPU mining after version 3.7.2  The packages are still available for download in the [repository](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/3.7/).  You will also want to tweak your settings for optimal mining consider the following resources:

- [Bitcoin hardware mining comparison](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/mining_hardware_comparison)
- [Litecoin hardware mining comparison](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison)

You will likely find litecoin mining to me most profitable with your setup, however it is up to you to determine your own results.  You will also need to launch cgminer with the --scrypt flag to mine Litecoins.

Per your request

BTC address:
16N1P6fDDbV2cLNFe5ZthMeMMZvrEHU2Ug

LTC address:
LN2T5Stvk6HNUpNCcV6dNzv9k7BoHFA9th

Answer (score 0):

OK here is what worked. Needed to find a working CGminer version for my computer.

cgminer-3.6.6-windows

command line
cgminer --scrypt -o http:// server_address -u user -p password --shaders 4000 --intensity 17 --worksize 128 -g 1

Thank you for your time

I will be sending litecoin to Mark that helped. I hope this helps someone else with same issue.

My Litecoin address LKQvQeknvu5i1EBjZwx5vd77YyjLcN1jSr